# kendo grid update\insert not working on IIS server but it is working on Local

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI Asp.Net MVC4 Q2 2013 everything is working fine on local but when i  am deploying it on IIS server it stop insert\update on DB and nothing happening event not throwing any error.

Comment: show us some code please.

Comment: Have you looked in dev tools to see if any errors are being logged client side? Also worth looking at the network tab to see if any request is being made, and what response is coming back.

Answer (score 1):

as pwdst mentioned, the best way to start debugging this is to look at the web page interaction with your server using the browser's debugging tools.  You're looking for the web page requests back to the server.  Following is example of how to do this in IE using my [jsfiddle example page](http://jsfiddle.net/Rick_Mortensen/Wtrb4/5/).  In this sample the grid is asynchronously loading data from the server.  This sample uses Jsfiddle's ability to simulate ajax requests (the POST request to jsfiddle's /echo/jason URL, which will simply reply back with the json data that we send it.)

```
read: {
    url:'/echo/json/',
    type:'POST',
    data: {
        json: JSON.stringify(testdata)
    }                
}
```

1. When the browser is started, click F12 to start developer tools.  This will open a new "Developer tools" window.
2. Click on the Network tab (this varies by browser version), and then click on the "Start" button to start the network trace.
3. Select the browser's normal page window and start the target page (or hit F5 to refresh it).
4. Select the browser's "Developer tools" window and observe the network requests sent to the server.  You can double click a specific request to see the details.  The problem is probably that the request is being sent to the wrong URL.

Comment: Thank You everyone i resolved this issue just removing grid properties.ServerOperation(False)

Comment: Good news!  Don't think my answer helped, but if it did, would you be willing to flag it as answered?  I'm a newbie and trying to get a few points :)

Comment: would you be willing to flag it as answered?-No